# length of sub-sequence in the string

Tags: c++, string, sequences

I need to implement `lastSeq` function,which gets as argument `string str` and `char chr`
and returns the length of last sequence of repeated `chr` (the sequence can be of any length)
for example:
`lastSeq("abbaabbbbacd",'a')` should return 1
`lastSeq("abbaabbbbacd",'b')` should return 4 
`lastSeq("abbaabbbbacd",'t')` should return 0

Is there C++ function which can solve it?

Comment: Ok. What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: There is no direct function for this, you will have to implement an algorithm using the various find functions available for string. See a good reference for `std::string` or C string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int lastSeq(char *str, char chr)  
{  
    int i = strlen(str);  
    int l = 0;  

    while(--i>=0)  
       if(*(str + i) == chr && ++l)  
          break;

    while(--i>=0 && chr == *(str + i) && ++l);  

    return l;  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This appear to be homework, so I'm just going to give you direction so that you can find the answer by yourself.

First, how would you do it yourself, without a computer to give the correct result for your samples. From those manual run, how would you generalize then in simple steps so that you can solve the problem for all different inputs.

By this point you should have a rough algorithm to solve the problem. What do you know about storage of string in C++, and the method that are available from that class? Can some one them be used to solve some of the steps of your algorithm?

Try to write a program using those function, to compile it and to run it. Do you get the expected result? If not, can you try to print intermediate state (using `std::cout << "Some value: " << variable << "\n";`) to try to debug it.

Once you have done all of that, and if you are still having issues, update your question with your code, and we'll be able to give you more directed help.